# How to DRY up routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In Rails 3, given routes like

```
get 'about/terms', :as => 'terms'
get 'about/privacy', :as => 'privacy'
get 'about/jobs', :as => 'career'
get 'about/feedback', :as => 'feedback'
get 'about/contact', :as => 'contact'
get 'about/us', :as => 'about'
```

How to DRY it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recon something like this would do it:

```
['terms', 'privacy', 'jobs', 'feedback', 'contact' ,'us'].each { |r|
    get "about/#{r}", :as => r 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if about is a controller or you hava a controller for your static pages

```
  ['terms', 'privacy', 'jobs', 'feedback', 'contact' ,'us'].each { |r|
      get "/#{r}", :controller => 'about', :action => r
  }
```